# Styling combobox dropdown in windows store apps (XAML)

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, styling

I'm trying to style the `ComboBox` control in XAML but haven't managed to style the colors in the dropdown/popup. The `ComboBox` seem to contain a `ScrollViewer` so I'm trying to style that. The items in the `ScrollViewer` is generated using a `ContentTemplate` and I guess I need to style it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [default system brush](http://metro.excastle.com/xaml-system-brushes). You can customize these colors by adding below line in resource dictionary.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxArrowForegroundThemeBrush" Color="MY_COLOR_HEX_CODE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Styling all `ComboBoxItem*ThemeBrush`es did the trick.